# ScrollViewer и смещение контента

Tags: c#, wpf

`StackPanel` обернут в `ScrollViewer` и при появлении скролла , смещается контент внутри `StackPanel`

Нужно чтобы контент не смещался.
Что можно сделать в этом случае ?

```
<ScrollViewer Name="scroll" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
    <ScrollViewer.Resources>
        <sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}">5</sys:Double>
    </ScrollViewer.Resources>

    <StackPanel Name="kontejner">
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

В StackPanel программно добавляю такие `textblock`

```
TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
textBlock.MinHeight = 20;
textBlock.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
textBlock.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
textBlock.Margin = new Thickness(10, 5, 10, 5);
```

Scroll появляется так:

```
    private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (KontejnerSoobshchenij.ActualHeight > scroll.ViewportHeight)
        {
            scroll.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
        }
    }
```

**Пояснение:**

Сколл появляется при наведении мышки на окно и нужно, чтобы он не изменял ширину `TextBlock-ов`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Показывайте скролл сразу, он же не может появиться снаружи. Хотя, если у `StackPanel` задана фиксированная ширина и контейнер выделяет столько места, сколько просят... В общем, показывайте код.

Comment: @АндрейNOP пост обновил.

Comment: А почему StackPanel + ScrollViewer, а не просто ItemsControl?

Comment: А так, сделайте `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"`.

Comment: @VladD - у `textblock` свойство `textBlock.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;` мне нужно чтобы оно работало. А с `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"` , до него дело не дойдёт.

Comment: @Vipz: Ошибся, имел в виду Vertical

Comment: @VladD а можно выделить под него место, но всё равно скрывать, а по необходимости показывать или же дать ему более верхний слой ?

Comment: @Vipz, как я вам написал в первом комментарии можно попробовать задать фиксированную ширину, а родительская панель пусть выделяет столько места, сколько просят (это может быть, например, Grid с колонкой в режиме `Height="Auto"`)

Comment: @АндрейNOP Работает!

Comment: Написал как раз ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы установите у `StackPanel` фиксированную ширину, а родительская панель будет выделять столько места, сколько у нее просят, то получится как раз поведение которое вам нужно:

```
<Grid Margin="5">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <StackPanel Width="100">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=tb, Path=Text}"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>

    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Name="tb" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
</Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Здорово, Спасибо!